# Display inspection warnings in the gutter on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

My Android Studio only displays inspection warnings in the scrollbar to the right of the editor, instead of the gutter to the left of it. It's just too time consuming to hover the mouse over each warning in order to find out exactly where it is.

Can I make it display icons in the gutter or something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't make it show warnings as icons in the gutter. However, there's no need to use the mouse to find out exactly where each error is. Instead, you can use Navigate | Next Highlighted Error and Navigate | Previous Highlighted Error (F2/Shift-F2 in the default keymap).